# Why is my code only finding the first table and not the second table on the wikipedia page?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have written a code that will parse a table from Wikipedia however I am only able to retrieve the first table on the page and not the second table which another list which i want.

```
import lxml
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


html = urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NIFTY_50')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
niftylist_raw = soup.find('table', {'class': 'wikitable sortable'})

nifty_symbol =[]

for row in niftylist_raw.findAll('tr')[1:]:
    nifty_symbols = row.findAll('td')[1].text
    nifty_symbol.append(nifty_symbols)

df =  pd.DataFrame()
df['Nifty Ticker Sumbol'] = nifty_symbol
print(df)
```

I would like to be able to append the list from the second table to the first table. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Because the other tables don't have a `sortable` class.

Comment: I don't see how you can append the first table to the second table. You could probably append the second and third table instead (both of which are not `sortable`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, look into your code. Can you see the difference how you look for a table and how you look for the rows? ;)

`soup.find('table',` -> returns only first

`niftylist_raw.findAll('tr')` -> returns a list

This means, you need to change `find` to `findAll` and add one outer `for` loop (to loop through single tables).